# Initial Fatal Error: Out of Memory on Wordpress after switching to suPHP

Tags: php, wordpress, suphp

I recently rebuilt Apache to include mod_suPHP (previously using DSO). But after switching to suPHP, Wordpress sites hosted on my VPS would return something like,

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2883584) (tried to allocate 77824 bytes) in /home/mine/public_html/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php on line 3522

However, if I refresh the page anywhere from once to about half a dozen times, the site loads up fine; and page no longer returns the error (in some cases I will need to go directly to the include to refresh). I thought it was a cache issue but I've cleared my cache and used machines on other networks to verify.

I could go to each WP installation and effectively get rid of the error, but new copies of Wordpress run into the same issue too. I've increased the memory limit to 256M with no luck. System wide, I'm only using roughly 80-100mb out of the 756 I have allocated. I'd appreciate it if anyone has any ideas on what can be done; would rather not re-provision the VPS.

Comment: "I've increased the memory limit to 256M" Where?

Comment: /usr/local/lib/

Comment: Hmm, I'm not following. Typically you increase memory limits in `php.conf` and `/etc/security/limits.conf`. What did you change?

Comment: Sorry, the php.ini usr/local/lib/. The limits.conf file appears to have nothing set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out 'RLimitMEM' in the Apache configuration file as suggested [in this post](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/suphp-problem-101709.html#post827311) appears to have resolved the issue.